# How to create a simple graph Using Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
sym t;
a = 10;
b=10;
V=6
v = 2;
p = 1:.1:20;
t = ((p./6) + (sqrt(b^2 + (a - p.)^2)/2))
plot(p,t)
```

I am getting an error whenever I am trying to plot this. 
The error is, 
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

but I have checked multiple times and I do not have an unbalanced parenthesis. I believe the error has to do with Element-wise matrix multiplication.

Comment: Why did you define `t` as a symbolic variable? Also the next to last line has a syntax error in it

Comment: " An error"?. "ERROR: The computer is on fire!". The solution to this is a fire extinguisher. My point: tell us the error

Comment: Did you mean `sqrt(b^2 + (a^2 - p.^2))`?

Comment: I made the edit... it was supposed to be (a - p.)^2.

Comment: why have you put a dot `.` after the `p`? that is causing the error

Comment: I am incrementing p by .1 decimal and i thought in matlab if you want to multiply a matrix times a scalar. you get a matrix. and I have to represent this multiplication with a dot.

Comment: scalar/matrix multiplication gives each matrix element multiplied by the scalar. Element-wise matrix/matrix multiplication requires a dot. See my answer and linked documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected code, with extra stuff removed which has no effect:

```
a = 10;
b = 10;
p = 1:0.1:20;
t = p/6 + sqrt( b^2 + (a - p).^2 )/2;
plot(p,t)
```

A note on element-wise operations:

You only have to use the dot `.` operator to enforce element-wise operations when something is happening between corresponding elements of matrices.

For instance, to get `[1 * 2, 3 * 4]`, you can do

```
[1, 3] .* [2, 4]
```

However, for `[6 * 1, 6 * 2]`, you can do

```
6 * [1, 2]
```

without the dot. It makes no difference, but it's worth always bearing in mind what you're actually trying to do!

For instance your original line was

```
t = ((p./6) + (sqrt(b^2 + (a - p.)^2)/2))
```

Here are steps for how I changed it

```
% no need for element-wise division for scalar 6
t = ((p/6) + (sqrt(b^2 + (a - p.)^2)/2))
% the dot after p does worse than nothing, it causes an error
t = ((p/6) + (sqrt(b^2 + (a - p)^2)/2))
% you need a dot to achieve element-wise squaring of the vector (a-p)
t = ((p/6) + (sqrt(b^2 + (a - p).^2)/2))  
% by the order of operations, you can remove extra bracketing to make bracket errors easier to diagnose
t = p/6 + sqrt(b^2 + (a - p).^2)/2
```

Documentation:

Array vs. Matrix Operations: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Order of operations: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Thank you for this. This makes a lot of sense. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @muhe no worries, nice to hear :) click the white/green tick at the top-left of this answer to accept it :)